# Barrier method applied to nonlinear conjugate gradient

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I have programmed a conjugate gradient method for a nonlinear program that works just fine.

Now, I would like to include some restrictions and I have a few doubts.

For the available possibilities, I think barrier method is a good option since I want a derivable function.

The restriction is simple $x<1$, so I update my new cost function such as:

$$F(x)=F'(x) + \sum \left(-\frac{1}{x-1} \right)$$

This creates an asymptote at $x=1$. But, after $x=1$ it goes to zero again, so, who is stopping the method to go towards $x \gg 1$?

Also, the method penalizes values close to $1$ but smaller than $1$. How to avoid that? Could a limitation on the step size solve the problem?

Comment: What are you summing over?

Comment: I am summing the non-compliances in order to avoid the method to go towards $x=1$, because at $x=1$ that function tents to inf. Isn't that right?